# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using this to get and fill table but getting an error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

I have tried JSON.parse and everything but still not working.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      var url = '@Html.Action("GetServices")';
      var data= ''

      $.get(url, data, function (response) {
          $("#tblServices").html("");
          $.each(response, function (i, val) {
              $("#tblServices")
                  .append($('<tr>').append($('<td>')
                      .html(response.ServiceID))
                  .append($('<td>').html(response.ServiceName))
                  .append($('<td>').html(response.ServicePrice)));
          });
      });
```

Comment: can you share `response` ?

Comment: You need to attach your response data

Comment: most probably your are returning html from the ajax call

Comment: @Stacky I am not sure why are passing `data` as empty string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the main reason for this can be the use of `@HTML.Action` here in this line below -

```
var url = '@Html.Action("GetServices")';
```

as `@HTML.Action` calls child action in a controller and return Html string as result. But as you are expecting a JSON data in the response it results in an error. It should be `@Url.Action()` instead which returns a URL to be called through $get method.